# How to open file with scp extension

Tags: matlab

I am trying to open a file which contains ecg data and has the extension .scp (it basically contains information about the pulse value vs the time measured)
Ideally, I would like to convert it to .mat file so that I could use MATLAB, but .dat would work too. By researching this, I found out it is a file which is usually used for securely copying some text file, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to extract the information from such a file.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I think you may be confusing things. `scp` is a *program* that is used to copy files securely over the internet. An `.scp` extension is probably something else entirely. Do you have a link to the file? It may be a simple text file. Otherwise, it is likely to be a proprietary file format for a particular application.

Comment: You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  For example, it would be great if we could see part of the file you are trying to work with, or maybe even just know where it came from.